# (WPF) How to keep GUI code from being a mess

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I have a GUI that is going to do a lot of disparate tasks. I currently have these separated in  a tab UI. The functionality that does all of the heavy lifting is split into separate classes, but what is left still looks like a mess. How do you organize the GUI functions in code so that everything is coherent? I'm working with WPF specifically, but general answers are also appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should have a look at the [Model-View-ViewModel design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), which is perfect for writing clean GUI code, clearly separated from business logic.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Thomas answer - MVVM if for GUI-non GUI separation. You should also separate GUI modules, and [Prism](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF) will help in that.